# Are you allowed to have an input without a value?

Tags: html, forms, input

Is the following allowed?

```
<input type="hidden" name="field" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is fine in hidden fields. It is only required in checkbox and radio inputs. It can never be specified with a file input. See http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_value.asp

Comment: Definitive link: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-value-INPUT, even though as Assaf says the HTML DTD/Schema does not enforce the radio/checkbox limitation. In practice of course browsers default the value to ‘on’ for these.

Answer (score 5):

[XHTML 1.1 schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/schema_module_defs.html#a_smodule_Basic_Forms) says that `value` is **not** mandatory:

```
 <xs:attributeGroup name="xhtml.input.attlist">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="xhtml.Common.attrib"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xhtml.InputType.class" default="text"/>    
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xh11d:CDATA"/>
    <xs:attribute name="value" type="xh11d:CDATA"/>
    <xs:attribute name="checked">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
          <xs:enumeration value="checked"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="size" type="xh11d:Number"/>
    <xs:attribute name="maxlength" type="xh11d:Number"/>
    <xs:attribute name="src" type="xh11d:URI"/>
    <xs:attribute name="tabindex" type="xh11d:Number"/>    
    <xs:attribute name="accesskey" type="xh11d:Character"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>
```

Comment: Question has the tag "html", which is different from xhtml 1.1.  Pedantry I realize, but anyone who is actively using xhtml 1.1 should be well-versed in said pedantry.

Comment: Question also has the <input> as <input/>, so clearly non-valid HTML but rather XML ...

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, form inputs are under your control to serve your requirements, so long as they're well-formed and valid xhtml.

It does seem a touch pointless though.

Comment: Saving transfer :P Although small, in this case, each call with will be missing 20 value="" and this call could be made 1000s of times for one user. The saving might be small, but makes the code a little cleaner...although less obvious.